# How to handle NoSuchElementException in Web Driver Java. I dont want to end test if element is not visible

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to identify an element. If the element is there, i will click and do some operation. If the element is not there, I just it need to record a message.

I have used `try`/`catch`, but the test fails when the element is not there. Could someone help me here. The below code throws an exception after waiting for the default timeout.

Note: Same question has been posted already. but only solution is to use `findElements`. I dont want to go with `findElements` as it takes a lot of time.

```
try{
    elemToFind = driver.findelement(By.xpath(".//div[@id='rightitems']");
    elementstatus = elemToFind.isDisplayed() || elemToFind.isEnabled();
    elemToFind.click();
} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
    report.updateTestLog("Element is not available", Status.FAIL);
}
```

Comment: _"the test fails when the element is not there"_ I may be out of my Selenium practice for a while. With what exception does it fail? If the element is present, but not visible, you have to catch [a different exception](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/ElementNotVisibleException.html) or actually use the value of `elementstatus`...

Comment: _"I dont want to go with findElements as it takes a lot of time."_ That's ... unlikely. However, you could use `By.id("rightitems")` which is considerably faster than using an XPath on old browsers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make absolutely sure you have imported [`org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/NoSuchElementException.html) and NOT [`java.util.NoSuchElementException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html).

Then it can't fail on the element missing. If it does, it probably fails with [`ElementNotVisibleException`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/ElementNotVisibleException.html) which you can prevent by testing your `elementStatus` before `click()`ing.

Comment: Thank you. its working fine now. I have another query, Can you tell me how to reduce wait time.

Comment: @user3326175 Do you mean implicit wait time? You have to set it some somewhere. Anyway, use [`driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(...)`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html#implicitlyWait%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
try 
{
    //Actions can be performed here
}
catch (RuntimeException ee)
{
    if (ee.toString().contains("NoSuchElementException"))
    {
        //steps
    }
}
```